# Sender's packet count is very big when we made calls using JsSIP

Tags: webrtc, sip, voip, wireshark, jssip

We are making calls using JsSIP. We are seeing "Sender's packet count" is very high in Wireshark. Can some one explain what is this Sender's count and why this count is so much big?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means **"total number of RTP data packets transmitted by the sender".**

RTCP packets contain statistics about an RTP session.

RTP packets carry audio and video stream data. So, high number of RTP packets is normal in most situations.